# Grails 3.2.4 grails-spring-websocket 2.3 Error

Tags: spring, grails, tomcat8, spring-websocket, grails3

=== UPDATE === (see original post below)

Though the bug fix initiated by zyro brought some improvements, there error is still not disappeared completely. It still looks like this:

```
31-Jan-2018 19:30:53.529 INFO [MessageBroker-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.setErrorState An error occurred in processing while o
n a non-container thread. The connection will be closed immediately
 java.io.IOException: APR error: -32
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:244)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:213)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:305)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:765)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:349)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:510)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:318)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.flushBuffer(ErrorPageFilter.java:318)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:159)
        at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSession
.java:350)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:318)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendHeartbeat(AbstractSockJsSession.java:251)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession$HeartbeatTask.run(AbstractSockJsSession.java:455
)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So actually only the second part of the error disappeared...

=== ORIGINAL POST ===

I find a lot off following erros in my Tomcat 8.0.28 catalina.out logs. I guess it is caused by the websocket plugin, which I used. I did the implementation in a service class like following:

```
def publishNewChart(def productId) {
        def linechart = chartService.getLinechart(Product.load(productId));

        brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/trade_chart/" + productId, linechart);
    }
```

And on the client side following:

```
$(function() {
        var socket = new SockJS("${createLink(uri: '/stomp')}");
        var client = Stomp.over(socket);

        client.connect({}, function() {

            client.subscribe("/topic/trade_chart/${product?.id}", function(message) {
                var messageJson = $.parseJSON(message.body);
                refreshPriceChart($.parseJSON(messageJson.data));
                brushed();     
            });
        });
    });
```

Does anybody have a clue, where the errors come from and how to deal with them?

Thanks a log in advance!

02-Mar-2017 13:15:33.349 INFO [MessageBroker-4] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.setErrorState An error occurred in processing whi
le on a non-container thread. The connection will be closed immediately
 java.io.IOException: APR error: -32
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:244)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:213)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:305)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:765)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:349)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:510)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:318)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.flushBuffer(ErrorPageFilter.java:311)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:158)
        at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSes
sion.java:350)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:322)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendHeartbeat(AbstractSockJsSession.java:255
)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession$HeartbeatTask.run(AbstractSockJsSession.java
:451)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ERROR org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to write SockJsFrame content='h'; nested exception is o
rg.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: APR error: -32
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:339)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendHeartbeat(AbstractSockJsSession.java:255
)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession$HeartbeatTask.run(AbstractSockJsSession.java
:451)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: APR error: -32
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:353)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:510)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:318)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.flushBuffer(ErrorPageFilter.java:311)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:158)
        at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSes
sion.java:350)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:322)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: APR error: -32
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:244)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:213)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:305)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:765)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:349)
        ... 22 common frames omitted

Comment: created a corresponding spring issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15307

Comment: thanks zyro! so it would be possible for now just to wrap the brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend() in a try-catch-statement and ignore the error? Or do I have to catch it at another place?